CMake - Shared library - Missing IDE support
I am working on a project structure that is published at:
https://github.com/veritacodex/IB.Cpp.Api.Client
You probably have seen a similar structure where:

There is a folder for a library, the one that I am trying to build.
A third-party folder where I leave any external .so
A playground/examples folder where I showcase users on how to use the library.

I managed to get all CMakeLists.txt files to work. It compiles and makes libraries nicely.
My problem comes when I try to use any object which is part of a shared third-party library. The IDE is not able to resolve any symbols.
I tried with Clion and VSCode and couldn't get any intellisense support. Am I missing anything in the way I link the external libraries?
These are the lines that link the third-party library:
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Library/inc)
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS YES)

ADD_LIBRARY(IbApiClient IbClient.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_DIRECTORIES(IbApiClient PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Third-Party/tws-api)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(IbApiClient PUBLIC libTwsSocketClient.so)


"The IDE is not able to resolve any symbols." - This is quite vague description of the problem. Instead, add to the question post the exact error message or other exact behavior of IDE which you treat as wrong. Also, focus your question post on a single IDE and describe how exactly you setup your project in that IDE.

ok thanks, I can understand that you don't have an answer to the question

I found a solution.
One way to make the IDE aware of the headers folder is by using the following:
FILE(GLOB TWSAPI_SRC CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
        "${TWSAPI}/*.h"
        "${TWSAPI}/*.cpp"
)

ADD_LIBRARY(IbApiClient IbClient.cpp ${TWSAPI_SRC})

Where:

TWSAPI_SRC is just the name I gave to the variable.
TWSAPI is the folder where the shared library source resides.

Full file at
https://github.com/veritacodex/IB.Cpp.Api.Client/blob/main/library/src/CMakeLists.txt
Clion can resolve all symbols if set up this way.
